# How to split dataframe column in R

Tags: r, substring

I have a column in a dataframe called parm_value that I would like to split into two columns,  lower and upper bound based on the position of the underscore in the field. I have been trying to use a combination of grep and substring with no success

Current dataframe format:

```
   parm_value
1       30_34
2       60_64
3       65_69
4       75_79
5       90_94
```

Desired data frame format:

```
   parm_value   lower_bound   upper_bound
1       30_34            30            34
2       60_64            60            64
3       65_69            65            69
4       75_79            75            79
5       90_94            90            94
```

I have been trying things like

```
dat02 <-
   dat01 %>%
   mutate(lower_bound = substring(parm_value, 1, grep("_", parm_value) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strsplit`:

```
library(data.table)
xmpl <- data.table(val = rep("65_45", 5))
xmpl[ , lower := sapply(strsplit(val, "_"), "[[", 1)]
xmpl[ , upper := sapply(strsplit(val, "_"), "[[", 2)]

xmpl
#      val lower upper
# 1: 65_45    65    45
# 2: 65_45    65    45
# 3: 65_45    65    45
# 4: 65_45    65    45
# 5: 65_45    65    45
```

If it is a really large table you can save runtime by only running the `strsplit` once, then calling the object when defining the new `data.table` fields.

`strsplit` returns a list:

```
strsplit("65_45", "_")
# [[1]]
# [1] "65" "45"
```

The `sapply` call iterates through the list with the subsetting function `[[` selecting the Nth item, where N is given in `sapply` as `sapply(some_list, "[[", N)`.

Comment: `1.9.5` has a function `tstrsplit` that splits and transposes the result, which makes this operation straightforward: `setDT(df)[, c("l", "h") := tstrsplit(parm_value, "_", fixed=TRUE)]`

Comment: @Arun That is awesome. I will look forward to `1.9.6`!

Answer (score 3):

You can try if your data.frame is called `df`:

```
cbind(df, `colnames<-`( do.call("rbind", sapply(df[,1], strsplit, "_")), c("lower bound", "upper bound")))

  #    parm_value lower bound upper bound
  #  1      30_34          30          34
  #  2      60_64          60          64
  #  3      65_69          65          69
  #  4      75_79          75          79
  #  5      90_94          90          94
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
out = cbind(dat, setnames(cSplit(dat, "parm_value", "_", fixed = FALSE),
      c("lower_bound", "upper_bound")))

#> out
#  parm_value lower_bound upper_bound
#1      30_34          30          34
#2      60_64          60          64
#3      65_69          65          69
#4      75_79          75          79
#5      90_94          90          94
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `read.table`

```
cbind(df1[1],read.table(text= as.character(df1$parm_value), sep="_", 
             col.names=c('lower_bound', 'upper_bound')))
#    parm_value lower_bound upper_bound
#1      30_34          30          34
#2      60_64          60          64
#3      65_69          65          69
#4      75_79          75          79
#5      90_94          90          94
```

Or `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
separate(df1, parm_value, into=c('lower_bound', 'upper_bound'), remove=FALSE)
#    parm_value lower_bound upper_bound
#1      30_34          30          34
#2      60_64          60          64
#3      65_69          65          69
#4      75_79          75          79
#5      90_94          90          94
```